# running microsoft crm 4.0 on Windows 7

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

Is it possible to run CRM4 in Windows 7?  Even if not officially supported, is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is *not* possible. The installer checks for the required operating system and will exit on Windows 7. You would have to patch the setup to remove this check.

I would recommend to create a virtual machine and install the environment into it.

See [the supported server versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979164.aspx).

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what the installer did.  Just exited.  I figured it would at least show a message!

Comment: It shows only a message if you start the server setup with SetupServer.exe in the /Server/<architecture>/ directory. If you start the setup with the splash screen, it will silently exit.

Comment: how do you explain this, then? :) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2009/09/18/microsoft-dynamics-crm-4-0-on-windows-7-windows-server-2008.aspx

Comment: @sJhonny he states only that (parts of)  Dynamics CRM 4 is compatible with Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any restrictions of running CRM on a windows 7 machine (actually I've seen a few people do it).

I'm assuming you mean the outlook crm client - if you're having issues with that the next easiest fix would be to use the CRM web client.

If you're talking about running the server application from Windows 7 I would strongly advise against this.  That server app definitely belongs on a full server OS - not a desktop.

Comment: There are no restrictions for the client. However the server itself only support Windows 2003 Server or Windows 2008 Server editions.