# install crm dynamics 4 on win 7

Tags: windows-7, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

this guy from microsoft [says it's no problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2009/09/18/microsoft-dynamics-crm-4-0-on-windows-7-windows-server-2008.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments), while another guy on SO says, 2 years later, that [it can't be done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5651131/537913).
When I try to run the CRM 4.0 installer on my win 7 pro machine, I get an error saying my OS isn't supported.
Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **still not** possible (server parts). The blog post only states that Dynamics CRM 4 is compatible with Windows 7 (or please show the quote to which you are referring to). However, this only refers to the Outlook Client (and the E-Mail Router)

Comment: yes, it uses the slightly confusing terminology "Dynamics CRM 4.0 will be fully supported on Windows 7" which made me think that the *server* could be installed on win 7, but obviously he meant only the client.